# Prevent Visual Studio from nesting Typescript files

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

How do I prevent VS2015 from nesting files in an ASP.NET v5 project?

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

I looked at un-nesting with Mads Kristensen's nesting extension, but he's said in an bug report on Github that it's not relevant to .NET5 projects because there is no .csproj to store the file relationships in. So it must be VS doing it itself. How do I stop it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? It bugs me!

Comment: no, i've just gotten used to it.

Comment: Haven't been able to figure this one out yet either, looked everywhere under the sun to stop it from nesting them!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this I accomplished it by manually editing the toolSettings.json file for VS as per this discussion https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/889

If you remove the rules for .ts files in the 'extensionToExtension' section it will stop the nesting. As the discussion says this is a temporary solution.